# Perform a calculation on one column based on two other columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

New to python and a student of data analytics. Need to complete my capstone-2 project (using Jupyter notebook) where I am working on a bigger dataset. I have made the following smaller dataset (hypothetical) for this question. There was a somewhat related solution found on stackoverflow, but did not address the kind of problem listed here (though the question seemed similar).

|  | date | state | county | cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3/1/2020 | Illinois | cook | 1 |
| 1 | 3/1/2020 | California | losangeles | 0 |
| 2 | 3/1/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 0 |
| 3 | 3/1/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 0 |
| 4 | 3/1/2020 | California | sandiego | 0 |
| 5 | 3/1/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 2 |
| 6 | 3/1/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 1 |
| 7 | 3/2/2020 | Illinois | cook | 3 |
| 8 | 3/2/2020 | California | losangeles | 3 |
| 9 | 3/2/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 1 |
| 10 | 3/2/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 2 |
| 11 | 3/2/2020 | California | sandiego | 1 |
| 12 | 3/2/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 2 |
| 13 | 3/2/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 1 |
| 14 | 3/3/2020 | Illinois | cook | 6 |
| 15 | 3/3/2020 | California | losangeles | 5 |
| 16 | 3/3/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 4 |
| 17 | 3/3/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 6 |
| 18 | 3/3/2020 | California | sandiego | 3 |
| 19 | 3/3/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 2 |
| 20 | 3/3/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 3 |
| 21 | 3/4/2020 | Illinois | cook | 8 |
| 22 | 3/4/2020 | California | losangeles | 5 |
| 23 | 3/4/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 4 |
| 24 | 3/4/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 7 |
| 25 | 3/4/2020 | California | sandiego | 3 |
| 26 | 3/4/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 3 |
| 27 | 3/4/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 3 |

```
The cases column has cumulative numbers. I need to create a new column which would give daily numbers and produce the following table:
```

|  | date | state | county | cases | daily_cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3/1/2020 | Illinois | cook | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3/1/2020 | California | losangeles | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3/1/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3/1/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3/1/2020 | California | sandiego | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3/1/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 3/1/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 3/2/2020 | Illinois | cook | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 3/2/2020 | California | losangeles | 3 | 3 |
| 9 | 3/2/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 3/2/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | 3/2/2020 | California | sandiego | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 3/2/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 2 | 0 |
| 13 | 3/2/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 1 | 0 |
| 14 | 3/3/2020 | Illinois | cook | 6 | 3 |
| 15 | 3/3/2020 | California | losangeles | 5 | 2 |
| 16 | 3/3/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 4 | 3 |
| 17 | 3/3/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 6 | 4 |
| 18 | 3/3/2020 | California | sandiego | 3 | 2 |
| 19 | 3/3/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 2 | 0 |
| 20 | 3/3/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 3 | 2 |
| 21 | 3/4/2020 | Illinois | cook | 8 | 2 |
| 22 | 3/4/2020 | California | losangeles | 5 | 0 |
| 23 | 3/4/2020 | Missouri | stlouis | 4 | 0 |
| 24 | 3/4/2020 | Illinois | dupage | 7 | 1 |
| 25 | 3/4/2020 | California | sandiego | 3 | 0 |
| 26 | 3/4/2020 | Kentucky | louisville | 3 | 1 |
| 27 | 3/4/2020 | Illinois | sangamon | 3 | 0 |

```
I tried the following code, but it does not produce the required result as it ignores state and county and just substracts from the previous row. How do I specify state and county columns in the condition?
```

df['cases_daily'] = df['cases'].sub(df['cases'].shift(1), axis = 0)

```
Any help will be appreciated. If a solution is already posted elsewhere, please point me to that as my search for a solution goes on. My understanding is that there is a solution already available to every question.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy way to add the new column you want.

```
d = {'date': ['3/1/20', '3/1/20', '3/1/20', '3/2/20', '3/2/20', 
'3/2/20'], 
'state': ['il','or','il','il','or','il'], 'county': 
['littlev','littlev','bigv','littlev','littlev','bigv'], 
'cases':[30,10,20,60,20,40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

my_list=[]
my_dict={}

for thing in df[['state','county','cases']].values:
    if thing[0] in my_dict:
        if thing[1] in my_dict[thing[0]]:
            my_list.append(thing[2] - my_dict[thing[0]][thing[1]])
            my_dict[thing[0]][thing[1]]=thing[2]
        else:
            my_list.append(thing[2])
            my_dict[thing[0]][thing[1]]=thing[2] 
    else:
        my_list.append(thing[2])
        my_dict[thing[0]]={}
        my_dict[thing[0]][thing[1]]=thing[2]

df['daily_cases']=my_list
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The code produces opposite result. I also tweaked your code a little as the 'daily_cases'  column is the new column that should come up after the code is executed. The second table in my post is the result I am hoping for based on the code executed on the first table.

Comment: What do you mean by the opposite result? The code block will create the column you are looking for in the second table?

Comment: 'cases' is the existing column and 'daily_cases' will be the new column I changed your code to mention 'cases' where ... for statement is
The last line was changed to mention 'daily_cases'. The code adds the numbers and not substract the first value under 'cases' from the second value under 'cases' (only when 'state' and 'county' names match up